# Is there another way to unit test business logic in mvc

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5, moq, repository-pattern

I have added a unit test to a mvc5 application manually.
This is my business logic

```
public void AddTreatments(TreatmentView model)
{
    using(var treatment = new TreatmentRepository())
    {
        var treat = new PhysiqueData.ModelClasses.Treatment()
        {
            treatmentID = model.treatmentID,
            treatmentCost = model.treatmentCost,
            treatmentDuration = model.treatmentDuration,
            treatmentName = model.treatmentName
        }
        treatment.Insert(treat);
    }
}
```

This is my repository used in the service layer

```
public class TreatmentRepository:ITreatmentRepository
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _datacontext;
    private readonly IRepository<Treatment> _treatmentRepository;

    public TreatmentRepository()
    {
        _datacontext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _treatmentRepository = new RepositoryService<Treatment>(_datacontext);
    }

    public void Insert(Treatment model)
    {
        _treatmentRepository.Insert(model);
    }
}
```

The next code is my actual unit test for my treatment and it is not working,
please can I get some guidance on it. I googled a lot of things and still can't get it right.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void AddingTreatmenttodatabase()
    {
        //var business = new TreatmentBusiness(new TreatmentRepository());

        var treatment = new Treatment()
        {
            treatmentID = 1,
            treatmentCost = 250,
            treatmentDuration = 45,
            treatmentName = "LowerBack"
        };

        var repositoryMock = new Mock<ITreatmentRepository>();
        repositoryMock.Setup(x => x.Insert(treatment));

        var business = new TreatmentBusiness(repositoryMock.Object);

        business.AddTreatments(treatment);

        repositoryMock.Verify(x => x.Insert(treatment), Times.Once());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Is there a error?

Comment: thank you sir! Finally I've understood what was my problem .. I was mocking my IRepository and the IClientBusinessLogic(Irepository) , but I forgot that in the middle is the IClientRepository, so now it is: IClientBusinessLogic(IClientRepository), and now I can test my BL.
With your problem I've solved mine, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

So you're instantiating a mock of `ITreatmentRepository`, setting up some behaviour and injecting it into your `TreatmentBusiness` class. So far, so good.

But then, in your `AddTreatments` method, you're instantiating a new `TreatmentRepository`, instead of using the one injected in via the constructor.

I'm assuming your constructor looks something like this:

```
public class TreatmentBusiness
{
    private readonly ITreatmentRepository repository;

    public TreatmentBusiness(ITreatmentRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    ...
}
```

In which case, your method should look like this:

```
public void AddTreatments(TreatmentView model)
{
    using (var treatment= this.repository)
    {
        var treat = new PhysiqueData.ModelClasses.Treatment();
        {
            treat.treatmentID = model.treatmentID;
            treat.treatmentCost = model.treatmentCost;
            treat.treatmentDuration = model.treatmentDuration;
            treat.treatmentName = model.treatmentName;
        }
        treatment.Insert(treat);
    }
}
```

Notice the usage of the field `repository`, as opposed to instantiating a new one.

As per Jimmy_keen's suggestion, in order to ensure your repository is properly instantiated and accessible throughout your class, a factory is advisable.

There are several ways you can achieve a repository factory, either you hand crank a dedicated factory and inject that into your constructor, like so:

```
public class TreatmentBusiness
{
    private readonly ITreatmentRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory;

    public TreatmentBusiness(ITreatmentRepositoryFactory repositoryFactory)
    {
        this.repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory;
    }

    ...
}
```

And that change the way you access your repository like so:

```
public void AddTreatments(TreatmentView model)
{
    using (var treatment= this.repositoryFactory.Make())
    //or whatever method name you've chosen on your factory
```

If you feel this is too heavy handed, you can opt for a method delegate (`Func<>`) and inject just a method that instantiates a new `TreatmentRepository`.

This would change your constructor like so:

```
public class TreatmentBusiness
{
    private readonly Func<TreatmentRepository> getTreatmentRepository;

    public TreatmentBusiness(Func<TreatmentRepository> getTreatmentRepository)
    {
            this.getTreatmentRepository = getTreatmentRepository;
    }
    ....
}
```

And you would change your method like this:

```
public void AddTreatments(string model)
{
    using (var treatment = this.getTreatmentRepository()) //Or this.getTreatmentRepository.Invoke() - same thing
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The way you resolve that dependency is up to you, either do it manually and inject that delegate like this when instantiating your Business object:

```
var treatmentBusiness = new TreatmentBusiness(() => new TreatmentRepository());
```

or you can use one of the many IoC containers/DI frameworks out there.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `this.repository` might not be usable after first call to `AddTreatments`, depending on `Dispose` implementation. To keep it more in line with OP's original implementation (and stay safe regardless of `Dispose`), factory/`Func` should be injected instead.

Comment: @jimmy_keen - Cheers for the additional edit, was strapped for time and didn't want to overly complicate matters but best practice should have come first :)